# Enumerating Target Device items in Deployment options

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have Visual Studio 2008 device project (.NETCF Compact Framework).
How can I programmatically enumerate elements (both GUIDs and names) available in combo box **Target device** (Devices -> Deployment options)?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Are you trying to get a list of all the possible project deployment options? If so, that would be a desktop application, not a compact framework application. (The device would have no idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the [Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545992%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) API. That should let you get a list of the available devices or emulators on the system.

For example, see: [Controlling Devices with the Smart Device Connectivity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384093%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/RemoteTool/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29 is a good starting point